# Target the last A element with conditionals

Tags: html, css, content-management-system

I need to target the last `<a>` element but with some conditionals.
In this case the text is created through a CMS which limit's me the option to add a class. I created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6xLpz6nj/8/) to show my problem. The last `<a>` must have an font awesome angle right in it's `:after` the other `<a>` elements not. I can't use something like `:last-child a` because the user/text writer doesn't have to write a link by default. There is also the possibility of another paragraph after the first. So nothing is default but the last `<a>` element which stands alone from the paragraph with some actual text must have an icon.

It's kinda hard to explain but the jsfiddle will explain itself so please take a look. it would be nice if there was a CSS solution. if not jQuery comes second.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: :last-of-type coud be an hint, but is it really in real ? https://jsfiddle.net/6xLpz6nj/10/ Does the container filled by user has an id, a class , a specific wrapper or sits always at  the same place in the tree of your template ? .We have not enough info for an efficient answer :)

Comment: in reality there is a container with classes wich contains all paragraphs. but no classes inside from there

Comment: okay, what about the link it holds ( href or title attributes), do they have something commun and peticular ? .... without your real cases, it will only be funny answers tthat you'll get

Comment: the fiddle give this `<a href='#'>`for any of your links, nothing usefull

Comment: They are all exactly the same. this is what the user editor looks like http://prntscr.com/dkjikd I can't tell the user to change the attribute or anything like that. I am currently thinking about a possibility with javascript/jquery to check wheter the paragraph with an `<a>` element has less than ~20 characters/text. and than add a class

Comment: what is the code generated for tha link read more ? **screen shots are no use** does it show read more when you hover it, if yes, CSS can do it example https://jsfiddle.net/6xLpz6nj/13/

Comment: I don't think I understand your last comment. but the `<a>` elements are all created the same way

Comment: What i am just asking is what is the html created by your CMS, so we can see if we can use the href or the title attribute to target tose specific links . run you cms , load a page and see source code of the page. If we do not know what kind of soup tag Your CMS produces , there is no good anwser to give.

Comment: Here is the page source http://prntscr.com/dkjndk

Comment: :), if this is really the code source of what's gonna be online, then CSS won'nt help here. javascript might ...

Comment: @GCyrillus I think i'll go with javascript then. Thank you very much for your time and patience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know it cannot be done using CSS alone.

How about JavaScript:

```
var element = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i=0; i < element.length; i++) {
    var el = element[i]
    var x = el.parentNode.innerText.length;
    var y = el.innerText.length
    if (x === y) {
        el.classList.add('icon');
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
.icon::after{
    content: "\f105";
    margin-left:5px;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

It adds an `.icon` class to all `<a>` elements which are not wrapped inline with text in the parent element.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you!

Comment: Is there any possibility to specify which `<a>` ? its always in a container with the class "block".

Comment: In the CSS file write: `.block .icon::after {...}`. Will that work for you? Will there be one container with the class `block` or several?

Answer (score 0):

You can target the last `p` tag.

```
p:last-of-type a::after{
  content: "\f105";
  margin-left:5px;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: that works for any last p of any portion of the document, we need more details ... see my comment i choose not to place as an answer :)

Comment: As I tried to explain. there are situations that there is no `<a>` element after the first paragraph but one in the first paragraph wich shouldnt get the icon.

Comment: @wilco, can you detail the structure of your template (see my comment), if you want an efficient answer